# Use Name in lookup_array

Tags: excel-formula

Assuming I have the following data in the sheet.

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | RED | 1 |
| 2 | GREEN | 2 |
| 3 | BLUE | 3 |
| 4 | COLOR | 1 |

And I define names for B1, B2, B3, and B4 as RED, GREEN, BLUE, and COLOR, respectively.

Next I'm using a formula like below

```
     MATCH(COLOR, {RED, GREEN, BLUE})
```

but Excel said formula error. I tried MATCH(COLOR, {1, 2, 3}) and it's ok.

So the question is, what's the correct way to use Name in lookup array?
[image: Name Manager]

Comment: add 0 as third parameter: `MATCH(COLOR, {RED, GREEN, BLUE}, 0)`

Comment: Why don't you just use a table and use the reference to the column?

Comment: Don't forget to use `"` for text. But in your examples, what are you trying to match exactly? Each example given would not return an actual match. Don't you mean `=INDEX(A1:A3,MATCH(B4,B1:B4,0))`?

Comment: @Ashgabyte Yes I forgot the 3rd parameter but adding the 3rd parameter still doesn't help.

Comment: @Enigmativity Using name is for readability.

Comment: @P.b in formula, RED etc is not a string, but the name for $B$1.

Comment: @kkaaii anyway you will get a value (a number), then use range B1:B3 as a second parameter

Comment: @Ashgabyte, Yes using range is also ok.

MATCH(COLOR, {1, 2, 3}, 0)  -> ok
MATCH(COLOR, B1:B3, 0) -> ok
MATCH(COLOR, {RED, GREEN, BLUE}, 0) -> error formula
MATCH(COLOR, {B1, B2, B3}, 0) -> error formula

Comment: @kkaaii - I think you're going to have the most readable, but buggy, spreadsheets ever.

Comment: You need explicit values e.g. `={1,"A",2,FALSE,}` i.e. `={B1,B2,B3}` also doesn't work. You could name the range `B1:B3` `COLORS` and do `=INDEX(A1:A3,MATCH(COLOR,COLORS,0))` instead.

Comment: @VBasic2008, I thought B1, B2, B3 is same as B1:B3 but seems it's not true. So what shall we do if the range is not contiguous, e.g. B1, B2, B4?